# Laravel Join Repeat result

Tags: php, join, query-builder, laravel-5

I was trying to us Join() in laravel 5 but I have some Problems I hope You Can Help me ,

```
$results = DB::table('words')
             ->join('users_words_relationship','users_words_relationship.word_id','=','words.id')
             ->where('users_words_relationship.user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)  
             ->join('translate','translate.word_id','=','words.id') 
             ->select('words.word','translate.translate')
             ->get();
```

this query did return repeat result like that

```
word    translation
Hello   مرحبا
Hello   اهلا وسهلا
Hello   مرحبآ
Hello   اهلا و سهلا
```

and I was trying also add groupBy() like that

```
$results = DB::table('words')
             ->join('users_words_relationship','users_words_relationship.word_id','=','words.id')
             ->where('users_words_relationship.user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)  
             ->join('translate','translate.word_id','=','words.id') 
             ->groupBy('translate.word_id')
             ->select('words.word','translate.translate')
             ->get();
```

it did return one result Hello right but didn't have all translation just one  !!

like

```
word    translation
Hello   مرحبا
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? It seems there are more than one translation of `Hello`. Which one are you trying to find? Grouping the results will only give one translation.

Comment: I try to get all of translation for the "hello" word like this result
`[word=Hello, translat= مرحبا, اهلا وسهلا, مرحبآ]`

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for group concatenation.

In Laravel your query will become

```
DB::table('words')
  -> join('users_words_relationship','users_words_relationship.word_id','=','words.id')
  -> where('users_words_relationship.user_id','=',Auth::user()->id) 
  -> join('translate','translate.word_id','=','words.id')
  -> select('words.word', DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT translate.translate) as translations'))
  -> group_by('words.word')
  -> get();
```

Comment: if the answer solves your problem, please accept it. Other people with the same problem will be able to find the solution quicker.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for following output

**word    translation**

**Hello   مرحبا**

**Hello   اهلا وسهلا**

**Hello   مرحبآ**

Use `distinct('translate.translate')`

Here is the query

```
$results = DB::table('words')
                 ->join('users_words_relationship','users_words_relationship.word_id','=','words.id')
                 ->where('users_words_relationship.user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)  
                 ->join('translate','translate.word_id','=','words.id') 
                 ->select('words.word','translate.translate')
                 ->distinct('translate.translate')
                 ->get();
```

Comment: thank you for your help but I'm looking for this result
`[word=Hello, translat= مرحبا, اهلا وسهلا, مرحبآ]`